# What is a Tent pole moment?

Tags: phrases

At a marketing meeting a speaker used the term *tent pole moment*.

I have no idea what she meant. Is anyone familiar with the phrase?

Comment: It's a marketing jargon usage, described [here](http://www.dailyfinance.com/2011/02/14/buzzword-of-the-week-tent-pole/). Probably alluding to the fact that a [central] tent pole holds the entire structure up, in which case it could be understood as ***pivotal*** (people who speak "normal" English are quite familiar with the concept of a *pivotal moment* in a meeting). But perhaps there's an allusion to *having a visible erection within one's trousers* (i.e. - an *embarrassing* moment), given that marketese (and the people who speak it) can be pretty puerile.

Comment: Could she possibly have said "tentpole movie"?  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tentpole_movie#English

Comment: Thank you for the information. The first definition makes sense.

Comment: lol: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tent%20pole

Answer (score 2):

If you are a camper, erecting your tent, the moment when you insert the center pole is critical to the stability of the entire tent. It is the same as a "sink or swim" moment.

Answer (score 1):

In the film industry, we talk about tent-pole movies, ones with broad, universal themes that everyone can relate to, and which can be expected to pull in diverse audiences. But there are also tent-pole moments in scripts, scenes that are pivotal, though often understated, that touch on universal themes and resonate deeply with people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).